# Storing and Accessing snapshot value from $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

In my global controller (assigned to the body in html) I have the following code to grab a snapshot of firebase one time.

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot;
}).then(function(data){
    $rootScope.content = data.val();
});
```

I am using the content in my HTML templates to render them. All the questions I found had resulted in putting the "then" code inside the callback.

Literally all I need to do is be able to grab a snapshot one time and store it on `$rootScope.content` and access it outside of the function, i.e. anywhere in my app.

I'm pretty sure it's because everything is rendering prior to firebase returning anything, I'm just not sure the best way to tell it to wait.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use Services instead of "rootscope"

Comment: Because all I need is a single snapshot, ONE TIME.

Comment: If you think services will work for getting the data ONE TIME and never pulling from Firebase again unless the user refreshes, then show me. I've never managed to achieve that.

Comment: I don't familiar working with firebase,But I suggest that option by using the knowledge of Angularjs. Try to learn about  how to use Services and why, That may resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
    $rootScope.content = snapshot.val();
});
```

Or:

```
ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    $rootScope.content = snapshot.val();
});
```

From the [`once()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) docs:

> **Return Value**
>   Returns a Promise that can optionally be used instead of the successCallback and failureCallback to handle success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second line `var data = snapshot;` may be the problem?  If all you want is to get the whole database and assign it to a object called `$rootScope.content`, or anything else, the below would work.  I don't use angular but `$rootScope.content` would need to be an object, aka `var foo = {}` would be able to take `snapshot.val()`.  Note that `snapshot.val()` is full of stuff other than just your JSON formatted data and you will have to extract out your individual nodes by calling the property names (the key's), e.g. `snap.val().firstName` to get `Bob`.

```
firebase.database().ref('/').once('value').then(function(snap) {
  $rootScope.content = snap.val();
});
```